# Juila Dataframe rollup by groups (aka subtotals)

Tags: dataframe, julia, dataframes.jl

What is a concise way to express rollup aggregations in DataFrames.jl?

Example dataset:

```
+---+----------+-----+---------+------+
| id|  date_col|group|     item|amount|
+---+----------+-----+---------+------+
|  1|2020-03-11|    A|BOO00OXXX|   1.0|
|  2|2020-03-11|    A|BOO00OXXY|   2.0|
|  3|2020-03-11|    B|BOO00OXXZ|  17.0|
|  4|2020-03-12|    B|BOO00OXXA|   9.0|
|  5|2020-03-12|    B|BOO00OXXB|   1.0|
|  6|2020-03-12|    B|BOO00OXXY|   5.0|
|  7|2020-03-13|    C|BOO00OXXY|   2.0|
|  8|2020-03-13|    C|BOO00OXXX|   1.0|
|  9|2020-03-13|    C|BOO00OXXY|   2.0|
+---+----------+-----+---------+------+

# desired output
+------+---------+
|group |total_amt|
+------+---------+
|ROLLUP|     40.0|
|    A |      3.0|
|    B |     32.0|
|    C |      5.0|
+------+---------+
```

I commonly need to summarize a dataset, sometimes for sharing reports, which aggregates values over certain columns with subtotals and grand totals. These are called 'rollups' or 'subtotals'/'grand totals' in Excel.

In Spark these are conveniently generated with `rollup` or `cube` aggregations. The above result is generated with the following spark api call.

How can I produce a similar table with Julia DataFrames.jl?

```scala
// scala spark
df.rollup("group")
    .agg(sum("amount").as("total_amt"))
    .orderBy("group")
    .show()

+-----+---------+
|group|total_amt|
+-----+---------+
| null|     40.0|
|    A|      3.0|
|    B|     32.0|
|    C|      5.0|
+-----+---------+
// note the aggregated column label is null for the subtotal (aka rollup)
```

NOTE: I am able to produce the result with multiple julia `groupby()` and `combine()` operations, and then union or vcat the result into a single dataframe.  I need and want a concise and readable idiom.

---

EDIT: adding a specific julia implementation to show why I want something more concise.

```julia
using DataFrames, Dates
df = DataFrame(id = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    , date_col = Date.(["2020-03-11","2020-03-11","2020-03-11","2020-03-12","2020-03-12","2020-03-12","2020-03-13","2020-03-13","2020-03-13"])
    , group = ["A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C"]
    , amount = [1.0,2.0,17.0,9.0,1.0,5.0,2.0,1.0,2.0]
    )

# replicate the spark.rollup example
df1 = combine(groupby(_, :group), :amount => sum => :total_amt);
df2 = combine(df, :amount => sum => :total_amt);
df2[:, :group] = [missing];
df_result = sort(vcat(df1, df2, cols = :setequal), rev = true)

4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ group    total_amt
     │ String?  Float64
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │ missing       40.0
   2 │ C              5.0
   3 │ B             32.0
   4 │ A              3.0
```

Adding a version of @bkamins answer, sticking with `combine()`
I think I prefer this answer so far, as it maintains a bit of symmetry and if made into a function is easier to see where the arguments would go.

```julia
using Chain
@chain df begin
    groupby(:group)
    combine(:amount => sum => :total_amt)
    append!(insertcols!(combine(df, :amount => sum => :total_amt), :group => "ROLLUP"))
    sort(:total_amt, rev = true)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
julia> using DataFrames, Chain

julia> df = DataFrame(group=["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"], amount=1:6)
6×2 DataFrame
 Row │ group   amount
     │ String  Int64
─────┼────────────────
   1 │ A            1
   2 │ A            2
   3 │ B            3
   4 │ B            4
   5 │ C            5
   6 │ C            6

julia> @chain df begin
       groupby(:group)
       combine(:amount => sum => :total_amount)
       push!(_, (missing, sum(_.total_amount)), promote=true)
       sort(:total_amount, rev=true)
       end
4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ group    total_amount
     │ String?  Int64
─────┼───────────────────────
   1 │ missing            21
   2 │ C                  11
   3 │ B                   7
   4 │ A                   3
```

This will be efficient and hopefully you find it readable.
As @jling commented we do not have in-built rollup.

Comment: Thanks @Bogumił, I feared this would not be a one-liner. My purpose is readability and maintainability in production code. This is a nice example, though I'd like to keep the symmetry of the summation call between the group and rollup, ie using combine in both cases.

Comment: You can use `combine` on `df` and use `vcat` with `cols = :union` to use combine both times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer with DataFramesMeta.jl

```
julia> using DataFramesMeta;

julia> @chain df begin 
           groupby(:group)
           @combine :total_amount = sum(:amount)
           @aside df2 = @combine df :total_amount = sum(:amount)
           vcat(df2; cols = :union)
       end
4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ group    total_amount 
     │ String?  Int64        
─────┼───────────────────────
   1 │ A                   3
   2 │ B                   7
   3 │ C                  11
   4 │ missing            21
```

Comment: I like the readability here, much easier for colleagues to maintain code like this. Adding another dependency is a slight burden worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

```
julia> df
5×2 DataFrame
 Row │ g      amt   
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     0      2
   2 │     1      1
   3 │     1      1
   4 │     0      1
   5 │     1      1

julia> combine(groupby(df, :g), :amt => sum => :total_amt)
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ g      total_amt 
     │ Int64  Int64        
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     0             3
   2 │     1             3

#alternative do-block syntax:

julia> combine(groupby(df, :g)) do sub_df
           (total_amt = sum(sub_df.amt),)
       end
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ g      total_amt
     │ Int64  Int64     
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │     0          3
   2 │     1          3
```

does this more or less do what you want? btw the relevant docs: https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/man/split_apply_combine/

I feel like we would need a feel iteration to solve all the things you might want to do in Spark, SO is hard to do those kind of back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I love the jl community. The requirements call for another row with the total over groups 0 and 1 (in this case total of 6).

Comment: @Merlin what would the `g` be for the new row? The issue is `g` column has element type `Int64`, "rollup" is not an `Int64`. So you would need to allocate a brand new column for that. IMH, it's easy enough to `sum(newdf.total_amt)`

Comment: @jiling Use the dataframe example I provided, or note the spark `rollup` command returns NULL for the rollup group. The solution you provide requires creating two aggregated dataframes and then combining them to produce the desired result. I'm looking for a **concise** expression to generate the result.

Comment: @Merlin ROLLUP looks like some internal special thing in spark, in Julia's DataFrame there's no such thing as a special "ROLLUP" object. What's not concise about current solution?